# list of strings into a list of tuples of ints

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

`['(128, 134)', '(134, 146)', '(134, 150)', '(137, 143)', '(137, 146)', '(137, 150)', '(143, 150)']`

I want to turn into a list of tuples of ints so this list will become:

`[(128, 134), (134, 146), (134, 150), (137, 143), (137, 146), (137, 150), (143, 150)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `literal_eval` from the [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module which will safely evaluate a string as a Python expression.

```
>>> a = ['(128, 134)', '(134, 146)', '(134, 150)', '(137, 143)', '(137, 146)', '(137, 150)', '(143, 150)']
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> map(literal_eval, a)
[(128, 134), (134, 146), (134, 150), (137, 143), (137, 146), (137, 150), (143, 150)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import ast
>>> L = ['(128, 134)', '(134, 146)', '(134, 150)', '(137, 143)', '(137, 146)', '(137, 150)', '(143, 150)']
>>> [ast.literal_eval(s) for s in L]
[(128, 134), (134, 146), (134, 150), (137, 143), (137, 146), (137, 150), (143, 150)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def to_tuple(x):
    ints = x.strip('()').split()
    return tuple(int(m.strip(',')) for m in ints)

print [to_tuple(a) for a in aa] # where aa is your string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
l=['(128, 134)', '(134, 146)', '(134, 150)', '(137, 143)', '(137, 146)', '(137, 150)', '(143, 150)']
t = [ tuple(map (int, re.findall("\d+", v))) for v in l ] 
print t
```

Comment: That will make tuples of strings, not of ints.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L = ['(128, 134)', '(134, 146)', '(134, 150)', '(137, 143)', '(137, 146)', '(137, 150)', '(143, 150)']
>>> [tuple(map(int, s.strip('()').split(', '))) for s in L]
[(128, 134), (134, 146), (134, 150), (137, 143), (137, 146), (137, 150), (143, 150)]
```

Answer (score 0):

just eval will do

```
[eval(i) for i in a]
```